# Not able to run the application, 'too much output to process' - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-logcat

Below is the xml code snippet. No changes were done to MainActivity.java. I had started making a calculator and was done with the designing part but when I tried to run this application (on various actual devices), Android Studio's logcat showed - 'Too much output to process' and it force closed on the device (Actual device, not the emulator). I had used shape.xml and strings.xml file. Nothing else!

**MainActivity.xml** file

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/asdjk"
    android:background="#ffc8c8c8">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="@string/w"
        android:layout_height="@string/h"
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/clearButtonString"
        android:textColor="#FFC85D00"
        android:textSize="30sp"
          
        android:layout_above="@+id/sevenButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fiveButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fiveButton"
         />
  
   <!-- lots of other buttons -->
  
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Shape.xml** file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
    <!--
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#ffc8c8c8" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: You're trying to map the `layout_height` of the `Button` to a string resource? 
I think it should be of a dimension type.

Answer (score 0):

> **android:layout_height** Dimension or keyword. Required. The height for
>   the group, as a dimension value (or dimension resource) or a keyword
>   ("fill_parent" or "wrap_content"). See the valid values below.

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html

Comment: So, can I define constant values for height and width in shape.xml - as an alternative to this?

Comment: Probably a better place to do it would be dimens.xml. Example:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>`

Comment: More here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: I was not able to link layout_width or layout_height to any of the .xml files, as far as I have tried, it accepted only - 'wrap_content', 'match_parent' and constant dp values. Am I wrong in this observation?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you are wrong. Which XML file is not what is relevant here. The layout_height, layout_width, etc.. will not accept strings. Or shapes. Or drawables.

You have to give it a value it expects. In this case, it expects either a numeric dimen value, or a keyword that's accepted, like match_parent.